# Pthread library for windows instead of UNIX

Tags: c

I need to use an unix library on my windows but I don't know how to do that.

With my linux this is working fine

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

But with my windows there is no such file or directory. Do you know where I can find the library ? 
Also, I'm using code blocks because I'm not on w10 so I can't get bash there.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not have native support for pthreads.  Compatibility libraries do exist, e.g. https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/ but I have never tried to use any of them and don't know how good they are.

Comment: Damn, that sucks :( Ok thanks...I guess I have no other choice to continue working with a virtual lagging linux machine :(